# Is there a convenient helper in Play 2.4.x to build a uri from play.api.mvc.Request.queryString

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, uri

I would have thought that `copy` on the `Request` with an updated `queryString` would have reset the URI however according to the code it's nothing more than brain dead vals.

https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.4.x/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/mvc/Http.scala

Something somewhere is likely to build the URI from such a Map[String -> Seq[String]] -- anyone know where that might be?

Much as I keep trying NOT to write code sadly I keep running into reasons to...

Most likely trivial EXCEPT there are always those stupid corner cases, languages, special characters, encoding and a host of other potential unknowns and if someone is already wearing those scars with pride I would prefer to honour their work by using it.

Comment: Your last paragraph a) made me smile b) tells me you are a very experienced dev c) reminds me why open-source software is awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @milkhouse Just battle-scarred - perhaps :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd absolutely do the same thing. :)

`play.api.libs.ws.WSRequest#uri` has the code:

```
  /**
   * The URI for this request
   */
  lazy val uri: URI = {
    val enc = (p: String) => java.net.URLEncoder.encode(p, "utf-8")
    new java.net.URI(if (queryString.isEmpty) url else {
      val qs = (for {
        (n, vs) <- queryString
        v <- vs
      } yield s"${enc(n)}=${enc(v)}").mkString("&")
      s"$url?$qs"
    })
  }
```

On GitHub it is [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play-ws/src/main/scala/play/api/libs/ws/WS.scala#L277).

Comment: Well even though I can't re-use it at least I can copy it :)

Worked like a charm!

Comment: I'll submit a PR for what you're asking foes

Comment: Damn phone. What you are asking for. Because I had the same need. Will let you guys know in here how it goes.

Comment: that would be awesome and much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend scala-uri for this:

https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri#query-strings\

I asked specifically about scala-uri's compliance to RFC 3986 (which handles the URI encoding edge cases), and they're aware of the issues and consider it their job to make sure they don't happen:

https://github.com/NET-A-PORTER/scala-uri/issues/81

There's also urlbuilder if you're using Java:

https://github.com/palominolabs/url-builder

As for why it's not in Play itself -- it's been discussed.  URI handling is a pain, but unfortunately it's one of those deceptively large features that's difficult to provide a Play wrapper over.  See the reference bug: https://github.com/playframework/playframework/issues/3247

Answer (score 0):

Try KFoundation's URL class. It is both a builder and a parser. It does decoding/encoding as well.

E.g.

```
val url1 = URL("http://exampel.net/path")
val url2 = url1/"subpath"        // -> http://exampel.net/path/subpath
val url3 = url2?("key"->"value") // -> http://exampel.net/path/subpath?key=value
```

API Doc: https://mscp.co/resouces/apidoc/kfoundation/scala/0.3/net/kfoundation/scala/io/URL.html
Dependency: https://search.maven.org/artifact/net.kfoundation/kfoundation-scala_2.13/0.3.1/jar